# Add typo on all sites of Stack Exchange as a general reason

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons, spelling

I propose to **add the typo close/flag reason on all sites of Stack Exchange sites** as a general reason instead of the "community specific-reason".

Instead of using different messages that says the same things, *all sites will use the same*. It could help everyone (users & voters).

For review, it will be *easier to filter* as in the Suggested Edit (only spam is taken) or Close vote (duplicate filtered).

*All sites could have typo*. It's a human mistake to type the wrong password, miss a key for the command, column name or don't understand the word in some language because it's wrongly written. It even has a tag here.

Is it possible to make the typo reason general instead of specific?

Comment: Avoiding downvotes is made easier by making suggestions that actually help. If a typographical error is so significant that it can justify the closure of a question, use the *needs detail or clarity* reason. But the vast majority of sites **do not close questions simply for having typos, nor do they need to**. This suggestion is not helpful, it shows a lack of research effort, and therefore it's getting downvotes just like on any site.

Comment: @Nij sure, but I can't predict what people will think. For me it's useful, that's why I posted it. Now, as I see people not agree with me, I try to delete the post, but I can't...

Comment: Exactly. You had absolutely no idea that this would be received poorly - because you had barely any idea of what you're suggesting, or why it would be pointless for the majority of sites. So, as with every site, please do research first, examine what systems would be affected by this, and consider whether there is any positive effect possible, pet alone how large it is.

Comment: We used to have a related reason network-wide, for questions that were only applicable to the author (of which typos are). I'd research why the "too localized" reason was removed across the network and replaced with specific reasons.

Comment: Please see [Resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/348025/4014959), which has info about the creation and rationale of the "typo" close reason. Please note that not all typo questions should be closed with that reason - common identifiable typos can be closed as dupes. But if a future reader with essentially the same problem is unlikely to discover the question through diligent searching then there's no point keeping it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a typo is the source of the error, letting OP know the issue was due to the typo is an answer.

For everything else - we can edit.

The question I'd ask is - *would*  you try to close a post where a typo is the source of the problem with a custom close reason, would it succeed, and is this a *common* reason to close a question?

Or would it be better to point it out to the poster in the form of an answer, especially if other folks encounter the same issue due to their own unique typos?

Fundamentally, I don't see the benefit from the proposal.

Comment: What I see from SO is that multiple people post their question then forget/leave etc. So, even by asking for changes, or telling the issue, the post can stay forever somewhere without answer and without way to answer it

Answer (score 10):

Closing a question about a movie because of a typo seems wrong.
Closing a question about redoing wiring because of a typo seems wrong.
Closing a question about killing bacteria inside of a dug well because of a typo seems wrong.

When would you actually *need* it?  Best for it to remain optional rather than something that applies network-wide.

Comment: When wiring, it could be because of wrong wire scheme took, for movie it could be because of wrong movie mention or idk, IMO typo could be almost everywhere at the time you can confuse things or miss a detail

Comment: @Elikill58 - in principle those are missing detail-type questions, which should be closed as "needs detail".  Saying that these could be construed as typos has ["Saturn is a tea" energy](https://www.reddit.com/r/AlignmentCharts/comments/k3b3mi/not_oc_we_love_forbidden_gutter_tea/) that I don't think is wholly appropriate